# Changing custom UIImage in didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom `UIImage` within my cell that I need to change when `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called. For some reason the image isn't changing, and I think it's because of my cell declaration inside the method.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var indicator: UIImageView!

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CustomCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.indicator.image = UIImage(named: "newImage")

}
```

How can I change my `UIImage` to "newImage" when the cell is clicked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create cell from index path

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        var cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CustomCell

        cell.indicator.image = UIImage(named: "newImage")

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Also, If want to change only one cell image in case of reusable cell in the table view, and rest others cell image data didn't affect, Similar to radio button functionality. So you can implement as follows:-**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell {

            cell.indicator.image = UIImage(named: "newImage")
            
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CustomCell {
       
            cell.indicator.image = UIImage(named: "oldImage")
        }
    }
```

**And then the output look like:-**

[image]

**And the other one:-**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a UIImage variable and change that image variable when the tableviewcell is pressed.

For example...

```
 var imageVar:UIImage = UIImage(named: "IM")

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell?

        let ImageView:UIImageView = cell!.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

        ImageView.image = imageVar


}


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

self.imageVar = UIImage(named: "Image")

self.tableView.reloadData

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 5

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MembersCell
        cell.member_status.image =  YourImage
}
```